# Kibana Dashboard Share without login required

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I want to share Kibana Dashboard in my website and allow anyone to view dashboard. I looked all over internet but could not find solution.

There are few solutions which talks about server setup but i am new to ELK stack and have no such great knowledge. Do anyone have solution to do it via program ... I am using python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use anonymous authentication when embedding Kibana objects - see the official docs at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/embedding.html#_authentication

Answer (score 2):

You need a proxy server to allow public access to Kibana dashboard.

Follow below steps to access to configure it (I am using NgInx).

1. Create a readonly user in Kibana & assign him 'kibana_dashboard_only_user' role
2. Generate a base64 credential as username:password from https://www.base64encode.org/
3. Setup an NgInx Proxy server
   1 - Open conf/nginx.conf
   2 - change location as below

   ```
     location / {
               proxy_set_header Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_pass http://localhost:5601; # url of Kibana
               proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic ZWxhc3RpYyGyGGFzdGlj";
           }
   ```